# Magento 2 REST API need only then needed custom_attribute rather getting all

Tags: magento2

On Magento 2 REST API I need to get an only a specific field for the sake of speed issue,

but now I can get a specific field like name, SKU, status, etc. But for the custom attribute, it get all the field.

But for custom, I can get a specific field rather getting all the field.

Currently, I am using this URL to get the response,

```
$ch = curl_init($storeURL."rest/V1/products?fields=items[sku,name,custom_attributes]&searchCriteria[pageSize]=10");
```

Now I can get that?